# My Hibernate CRUD is not saving data in the table, but its showing the table empty

Tags: java, html, database, hibernate, crud

My program is suppose to take different information from the user to save people in the table, but its not saving the information in the table, when I ask to print it, it just prints the table empty. And when I look into the DataBase and View Data on the table, it doesnt save them there either.

Here is the HTML of entering information.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<body>
    <ui:composition template="./plantilla/plantilla.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="head">
        </ui:define>
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h4>Ingresar Información</h4>
            <hr/>
            <h:form id="formulario">
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h:outputLabel value="Identificación" for="id" class="control-label col-sm-3"/>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <h:inputText id="id" required="true" class="form-control"
                                         requiredMessage="Campo requerido"
                                         value="#{ingresar.identificacion}">
                            </h:inputText>
                            <h:message for="id" class="text-danger"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h:outputLabel value="Nombre" for="nombre" class="control-label col-sm-3"/>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <h:inputText id="nombre" required="true" class="form-control"
                                         requiredMessage="Campo requerido"
                                         value="#{ingresar.nombre}">
                            </h:inputText>
                            <h:message for="nombre" class="text-danger"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h:outputLabel value="Apellido 1" for="apellido1" class="control-label col-sm-3"/>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <h:inputText id="apellido1" required="true" class="form-control"
                                         requiredMessage="Campo requerido"
                                         value="#{ingresar.apellido1}">
                            </h:inputText>
                            <h:message for="apellido1" class="text-danger"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h:outputLabel value="Apellido 2" for="apellido2" class="control-label col-sm-3"/>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <h:inputText id="apellido2" required="true" class="form-control"
                                         requiredMessage="Campo requerido"
                                         value="#{ingresar.apellido2}">
                            </h:inputText>
                            <h:message for="apellido2" class="text-danger"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="text-align: center;">
                        <h:commandButton value="Guardar" action="#{ingresar.guardarInformacion}"/>
                    </div>                        
                </div>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</body>
```

Here is the HTML to show the dataTable.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">

<body>
    <ui:composition template="./plantilla/plantilla.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <p:dataTable var="persona" value="#{verestudiante.personas}" rows="5" paginator="true">
                <p:column headerText="Identificacion">
                    <h:outputText value="#{personas.identificacion}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Nombre">
                    <h:outputText value="#{personas.nombre}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Primer Apellido">
                    <h:outputText value="#{personas.apellido1}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Segundo Apellido">
                    <h:outputText value="#{personas.apellido2}"/>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </ui:define>

    </ui:composition>

</body>
```

Here is the POJO with all the variables from the people we are entering to the Database.

```
public class Persona {
private int idPersona;
private String nombre;
private String apellido1;
private String apellido2;
private String identificacion;


public static Persona getPersona(Persona personaParametro){
    Persona persona = new Persona();
    persona.idPersona = personaParametro.idPersona;
    persona.nombre = personaParametro.nombre;
    persona.apellido1 = personaParametro.apellido1;
    persona.apellido2 = personaParametro.apellido2;
    persona.identificacion = personaParametro.identificacion;
    return persona;
}

public int getIdPersona() {
    return idPersona;
}

public void setIdPersona(int idPersona) {
    this.idPersona = idPersona;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getApellido1() {
    return apellido1;
}

public void setApellido1(String apellido1) {
    this.apellido1 = apellido1;
}

public String getApellido2() {
    return apellido2;
}

public void setApellido2(String apellido2) {
    this.apellido2 = apellido2;
}

public String getIdentificacion() {
    return identificacion;
}

public void setIdentificacion(String identificacion) {
    this.identificacion = identificacion;
}
```

}

Here is the HibernateUtil we used in the CRUD.

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

static {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
        // config file.
        //sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        sessionFactory = new org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Log the exception. 
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

}

The managedBean(requestedScope) we used to create the list of people to call in the HTML dataTable and the table in the Database.

```
public class verestudiante{
private List<Estudiante> personas = new ArrayList<Estudiante>();

public List<Estudiante> getPersonas() {
    return personas;
}

public verestudiante() {
}

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    EstudianteGestion personaGestion = new EstudianteGestion ();
    personas = personaGestion.readPersonas();
}
```

}

Here is the managedBean(requestedScope) we used to insert the information in the first HTML code.

```
/**
 * Creates a new instance of ingresar
 */
public ingresar() {
}

public String guardarInformacion(){  
    PersonaGestion personaGestion = new PersonaGestion();
    Persona persona = Persona.getPersona(this);
    personaGestion.createPersona(persona);
    return "verestudiante";
}
```

}

And finally, heres the CRUD.

```
public class PersonaGestion {

public void createPersona(Persona persona){
    Session session = null;
    try{
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        persona.setIdPersona((ultimoId() + 1));
        session.save(persona);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        session.close();
    }        
}

public int ultimoId(){
    Session session = null;
    try{
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Persona ultimo = (Persona) session.createCriteria(Persona.class)
                .addOrder(Order.desc("idPersona")).setMaxResults(1).uniqueResult();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return ultimo.getIdPersona();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        session.close();
    } 
    return -1;
}

public List<Persona> readPersonas(){
    Session session = null;
    try{
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        //Leer la informacion que esta en BD
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Tabla");
        List<Persona> lista = query.list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return lista;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        session.close();
    } 
    return null;
}

public Persona readPersona(String identificacion){
    Session session = null;
    try{
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        //leer una sola persona por identificacion
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Persona where identificacion = :identificacionParametro");
        query.setParameter("identificacionParametro", identificacion);
        List<Persona> lista = query.list();
        if(lista.size() > 0)
            return lista.get(0);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        session.close();
    } 
    return null;
}

public void updatePersona(Persona persona){
    Session session = null;
    try{
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.update(persona);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        session.close();
    } 
}

public void deletePersona(Persona persona){
    Session session = null;
    try{
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.delete(persona);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        session.close();
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: have you tried debugging and saw if your html is setting the values correctly in the DTO before saving?

Comment: I just debugged and it seems is passing through everything fine, but im not quite sure if its setting the values correctly in the DTO, where should I put the breakpoints to know correctly?

Comment: Your function ultimoId(), what does it do? Return the maximum ID in the database table? so you can add+1 while adding the ID? Why isn't this column an auto incremented ID. You can try adding a breakpoint to the createPersona(Persona persona) method, and inspect the object persona to see if the values exist or not. Also I can not see where you have mapped your DTO/POJO to hibernate.

Comment: The function ultimoId() is suppose to take a count on the number of people in the list, is also the primary key of the Table on the DB, so it makes the ID for every person and when you enter a new one it adds 1 to the number from the last person that was entered. If im not mistaken the Hibernate is mapped to Persona

Comment: Is it throwing out any exception? Are the tables in your database named correctly?

Comment: They are, there is idPersona for the primary key, then it goes for "nombre", "apellido1","apellido2","identificacion", also is not throwing any exception, it just prints the table empty, after I pressed the button to save the information.

Comment: your code seems to be fine and I can not find a problem with it. Either the values are not being defined correctly in the DTO, or it might be throwing an exception.

Please try to debug the `createPersona` and before the line `session.save(persona);` inspect your persona object and see if the values are correclty defined, and all of them are correct.

Comment: Ok, I will do that, thank you for your help and time. Ill be sure to update as soon as I do that and if I manage to fix it too.

Comment: I just did debugged, it says it is saving the right information in each variable of persona correctly. The only thing is that idPersona is at 0, instead of being at 1.

Comment: Try setting a hard coded default value of 1 for one time and see if it saves?

Comment: Also use saveOrUpdate function of hibernate orm

Comment: I tried putting the value idPersona set at 1 in the POJO directly when I declare it, but it somehow still shows it on 0 when saved.

Comment: Is there a way to make it save exclusively in the table of the DB, when I see View Data on it, to just show on it, I dont need it to show on the browser itself. Just enter the information on the browser and make it show on the table inside the IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after reading your code clearly one more time, the error is in the line.

```
return ultimo.getIdPersona();
```

There is no data in the table when you are running it for the first time, so the above line would throw a NullPointerException. After this exception you catch it and you return -1 as given in the code:

```
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
finally{
    session.close();
} 
return -1;
```

When you return -1 the personaId becomes 0, in the line

```
persona.setIdPersona((ultimoId() + 1));
```

This 0 is causing error while saving the data. A good way to approach this problem is to change your structure of the primary key, it should be auto incremented defined in the database and in the mapping you should set the generator to `identity` instead of `assigned`.

```
<generator class="identity"></generator>
```

Or if you just want to run your code correctly, you should do the following in your `ultimo` function.

```
session.beginTransaction();
Persona ultimo = (Persona) session.createCriteria(Persona.class)
                .addOrder(Order.desc("idPersona")).setMaxResults(1).uniqueResult();
session.getTransaction().commit();
return ultimo !=null ? ultimo.getIdPersona() : 1;
```

You would return 1 and the first object would be stored correctly in your database. You would never face this problem afterwards.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I would be glad if you could also upvote my answer. Thanks @LuisSequeira